# NSLayoutConstraint issue on tableView

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I was trying to make a custom UITableViewCell, and when I add this uiview to my cell it seems theres a problem on my constraints. Can you help me trace the layout or constraints error..

[image]

[image]

Comment: what you did is fine, but you added some extra constraint or invalid constraint which lead to this error. for example, in one constraint you say a>100 and in other place a<10 which is not possible and invalid. as the auto layout calculates view's frames based on constraints, and as they are invalid,it gives this error. check all the constraints properly once and make sure they make sense.

Comment: Delete this constraints : Horizontal Space - (10) - Date of Service - MAIN_VIEW

Comment: @santhu yeah thats perfect but, I cant find which if the constraints that makes it invalid. I'd reviewed all the constraints and it seems fine with me. Can you please help me retrace it :)

Comment: @RajSubbiah thanks, I'd tried your idea but it didn't do anything. The issues is on Vertical spacing I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Priority for constraints. By default all constraints have 1000 points of priority. It's call conflicts. Just set priority for constraint `V:[UIButton]-(10)-[UIButton]` like height(750 points) and its solve your trouble. Or set not equal(==) constrains, but set >=,<=.

p.s. in visual format constraints between buttons needs like `@"V:[button1]-(10@750)-[button2]"` or `@"V:[button1]-(>=10)-[button2]"`